# clustering in network vanet +files mobility craeted with sumo+ns2

Tags: networking, network-programming, ns2, sumo

I want to create multiple clusters on a road with mobility files created with somo in ns2.
The file `mobility.tcl` is mobility in sumo.

My code is as follows:

```
set val(chan)           Channel/WirelessChannel    ;# channel type
set val(prop)           Propagation/TwoRayGround   ;# radio-propagation model
set val(netif1)         Phy/WirelessPhy            ;# network interface type
set val(netif2)         Phy/WirelessPhy            ;# network interface type
set val(mac)            Mac/802_11p                ;# MAC type
set val(ifq)            Queue/DropTail/PriQueue    ;# interface queue type
set val(ll)             LL                         ;# link layer type
set val(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna        ;# antenna model
set val(ifqlen)         400                        ;# max packet in ifq
set val(nn)             747                        ;# number of mobilenodes
set val(rp)             DSDV                       ;# routing protocol
set opt(x)              6162
set opt(y)              6029
# ======================================================================
# Main Program
# =====================================================================
#
# Initialize Global Variables
#
set ns_     [new Simulator]
# set up for hierarchical routing
$ns_ node-config -addressType hierarchical

AddrParams set domain_num_ 10         
lappend cluster_num 2 6 2 3 6 1 5 5 2 6                  
AddrParams set cluster_num_ $cluster_num
lappend eilastlevel 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20             
AddrParams set nodes_num_ $eilastlevel 
set tracefd     [open paris.tr w]
$ns_ trace-all $tracefd
set namf  [open paris.nam w]
$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namf $opt(x) $opt(y)
# set up topography object
set topo       [new Topography]
$topo load_flatgrid $opt(x) $opt(y)
#
# Create God
#
create-god $val(nn)
# configure node
    $ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
         -llType $val(ll) \
         -macType $val(mac) \
         -ifqType $val(ifq) \
         -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
         -antType $val(ant) \
         -propType $val(prop) \
         -phyType $val(netif1) \
         -channelType $val(chan) \
         -topoInstance $topo \
         -agentTrace ON \
         -routerTrace ON \
         -macTrace OFF \
         -movementTrace ON 

            for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
    set node_($i) [$ns_ node]   
    $node_($i) random-motion 0      ;# disable random motion
            $ns_ initial_node_pos $node_($i) 30
             }
     $ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
         -llType $val(ll) \
         -macType $val(mac) \
         -ifqType $val(ifq) \
         -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
         -antType $val(ant) \
         -propType $val(prop) \
         -phyType $val(netif2) \
         -channelType $val(chan) \
         -topoInstance $topo \
         -agentTrace ON \
         -routerTrace ON \
         -macTrace OFF \
         -movementTrace ON 

        for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
    set node_($i) [$ns_ node]   
    $node_($i) random-motion 0      ;# disable random motion
            $ns_ initial_node_pos $node_($i) 30
             }
     source mobility.tcl

    set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
    $ns attach-agent $n(0) $udp0
    set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
    $cbr0 attach-agent $udp0
    set udp1 [new Agent/UDP]
    $ns attach-agent $n(1) $udp1
    $udp1 set class_ 1
    set cbr1 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
    $cbr1 attach-agent $udp1
    set null0 [new Agent/Null]
    $ns attach-agent $n(50) $null0
    set null1 [new Agent/Null]
    $ns attach-agent $n(80) $null1
    $ns connect $udp0 $null0
    $ns connect $udp1 $null1
    $ns at 1.0 "$cbr0 start"
    $ns at 1.1 "$cbr1 start"
    set tcp [new Agent/TCP]
   $tcp set class_ 2
   set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
    $ns_ attach-agent $node_(0) $tcp
    $ns_ attach-agent $node_(22) $sink
    $ns_ connect $tcp $sink
    set ftp [new Application/FTP]
    $ftp attach-agent $tcp
    $ns_ at 10.0 "$ftp start" 
     #
     # Tell nodes when the simulation ends
     #
      for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
   $ns_ at 500.0 "$node_($i) reset";
     }
      $ns_ at 500.0 "stop"
    $ns_ at 1000.01 "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns_ halt"
     proc stop {} {
global ns_ tracefd
$ns_ flush-trace
close $tracefd
   }
   puts "Starting Simulation..."
   $ns_ run*
```

And the error is:

> ```
> madani@ubuntu:~/champ elysees$ ns paris2.tcl
>   num_nodes is set 747
>   Error!!
>   str2addr:Address 32573 outside range of address field length 2048*
> ```

Comment: 1) No SUMO mobility file is connected to your file. 2) Please have a look at the tested clustering examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNM3g4d3FBRXFDM3c/view?usp=sharing ... 3) And vanet examples with connected sumo files http://neo.lcc.uma.es/staff/jamal/vanet/?q=node/11 → urban-VANET-scenario-U1.tar.gz, urban-VANET-scenario-U2.tar.gz, urban-VANET-scenario-U3.tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost OK, when some typos are edited. `Mac/802_11p` is today `Mac/802_11Ext`. Unless you used an old patch for 802_11p and failed the build. But I guess it's a typo. Using hierarchical: The nodes must be created hierarchical. A simple "node creation" will cause

> Address 32573 outside range of address field length 2048

Typos: `ns` has two definitions, `ns` and `ns_` .

`node` has two definitions, `n` and `node_` ..... Easily fixed with :

```
$ sed -i 's/ns/ns_/g' somiMadani.tcl && sed -i 's/ns__/ns_/g' somiMadani.tcl

$ sed -i 's/n(/node_(/g' somiMadani.tcl
```

The simulation: I used a SUMO mobility file with 40 nodes: `mobmod-teatinos-M40A.tcl`, from  http://neo.lcc.uma.es/staff/jamal/vanet/?q=node/11 . Segmentation fault happens when the trace files are about 80MB, which is usable. Nam animation: OK. The edited file, somiMadani-vanet.tcl → → Dropbox → https://www.dropbox.com/s/sv7p4tqc6pk0oje/somiMadani-vanet.tcl?dl=0 And readable, somiMadani-vanet.tcl.txt https://www.dropbox.com/s/fy8valous07m5er/somiMadani-vanet.tcl.txt?dl=0

Edit, Jun 5. Hierarchical: Creating the required hierarchical nodes: See `ns-2.3x/tcl/{ex/{hier-rtg-10.tcl, hts100-0.tcl, test/hts1000.tcl}` → → hts100-0.tcl, hts1000.tcl are used by
used by hier-rtg-100.tcl, hier-test-1000.tcl.

New example, your code + the hts100-0.tcl snippet "n-hts120-0.tcl": Vanet_n-802.11p.tar.gz  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNcVcwSXhPWGUycDA/view?usp=sharing